# Problem with connecting to Raspberry pi after setting a shutdown

Tags: ssh

using pianobar and utilizing a reboot delay and screens, I was running a headless pandora that was shutting off by itself. Pretty nice.

I used two screens (typing screen bash) one running pianobar and the other running the command:

> sudo shutdown -r 22:15

It's the next day and I've been trying to connect and this is what I'm getting:

> ~$ ssh pi@192.***.*.**
>   pi@192.***.*.*'s password:
>   The system is going down on Fri Jun 28 22:15:51 2013
>
> ~$

As you see, it's unlikely the date will be June 28 2013 again for awhile as it's Jun 29 2013 for me...
I don't have any feasible way of connecting it with a monitor and usb keyboard (I have neither) and I'd rather not lose the scripts I wrote into it which I conveniently forgot to backup.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

I recovered the scripts and grabbed my samba config file which is great!
Before I dd the sd card (again) is there anyway I can cancel the shutdown by modifying a file on the card?
I ran:

> grep -r "22:15" /path/to/sd/card

which didn't get me especially far. the 22:15 is the time to shutdown.

Answer (score 2):

you may revive and save your scripts by connecting SD card to another Linux box using SD card reader.

you may check the condition of your Raspberry Pi system by connecting the TV as a monitor using HDMI cable. if you don't have neither, your parents, friends, girlfriends or neighbours might have and let you use it for a while, if asked nicely and brought something like a 6-pack in return =)

Comment: My laptop has a sd card reader and this worked perfectly.  Even if I can't save the the os, this saved a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

I got myself stuck in this situation for 2 days after issuing an scheduled shutdown, but the solution is trivial:

You need only to get USB keyboard. Plug it to the RPi, power it, wait a few minutes for the system to boot up completely then press

CTRL+ALT+DEL

the system should shutdown properly and clean any scheduled shutdown that was preventing you to log in.

TIP: Avoid issuing delayed shutdown on the RPi for it has no Real Time Clock. Then if the power fails after the scheduled shutdown is issued you may not be able to log in (on screen or with SSH) to the RPi again until you hook it to a keyboard.